# Basemap Qualitative Colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib-basemap

Given [this data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_362EczI3TlcWNnZThiQ2hBVVE/view?usp=sharing) (a CSV output of a subset of this shape file for some counties in southeastern Michigan, along with some data I have added), I am attempting to use basemap to produce a map that looks something like this:

[image]

I was able to produce the above map by modifying the code from [this tutorial](http://brandonrose.org/pythonmap#Plotting-the-Map).

I really want the black-colored polygons to be this color: `'#5f9ed1'` and the grey-colored polygons to be this color: `'#c85200'`.

I am trying to avoid using a set of bins and a color map, as explained [in the tutorial](http://brandonrose.org/pythonmap#Plotting-the-Map).

I'd really just like to refer to the `'Color'` field in the linked CSV file from above and pass those values as the colors of their corresponding polygons in the data frame (I prefer to use Pandas as much as possible).

Is this possible with `basemap`?

Sample code is quite involved and will take a while to prepare, but I can include it if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding a code sample should be a given. You should definitely add it since it would surely help anyone attempting to answer this question.

Comment: You're right. I'll try to provide some code today.